# MVC Model Binding Post Values Best Practice

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-binding

I'm trying to figure out if what I'm doing is flawed or acceptable.  Specifically, I'm questioning the NULL value I'm getting back in the POST to Controller in 'Timeframes' property. The 'Timeframe' (singular) property DOES contain the value so all is good.  However, is this just how model binding works and the property (Timeframes) that is used to populate the DDL comes back as null? Is this best practice and what I'm doing is fine?  Is this a concern of sending values around that are not needed...performance concern?

Timeframe = used to return value back to Controller on Post

Timeframes = used to populate DDL values

Drop Down List Box on View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Timeframe, Model.Timeframes)
```

Model:

```
public class ABCModel
{
    public List<SelectListItem> Timeframes { get; set; }
    public string Timeframe { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public void TestControllerMethod(ABCModel model)
{
    //this value is null. 
    var timeFrames = model.Timeframes;

    //this value is populated correctly
    var timeFrame = model.Timeframe;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A form only posts back the name/value pairs of its successful controls. You have created a form control for property `Timeframe`, so you get the value of the selected option in the POST method.

You have not (and should not), created form controls for each property of each `SelectListItem` in your `Timeframes` property, so nothing relating to it is send in the request when the form is submitted, hence the value of `Timeframes` is `null`.

If you need to return the view because `ModelState` is invalid, then you need to re-populate the `TimeFrames` property as you did in the GET method (otherwise your `DropDownListFor()` will throw an exception). A typical implementation migh look like

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ABCModel model = new ABCModel();
    ConfigureViewModel(model);
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ABCModel model)
{
    if (!modelState.IsValid)
    {
        ConfigureViewModel(model);
        return View(model);
    }
    // Save and redirect
}

private void ConfigureViewModel(ABCModel model)
{
    model.TimeFrames = ....; // your code to populate the SelectList
}
```